# Unicode characters become question marks (C++ and MFC Dialog Based App)

Tags: c++, mysql, unicode, mfc

These codes sets the values to editbox. But I'm having trouble when I retrieve Unicode characters from MySQL table.

For example, string `nüşabə` sets as `nÃ¼ÅŸabÉ™`.

Here is my codes.

```
void CmysqlDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    USES_CONVERSION;

    try
    {
        mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver = new mysql::MySQL_Driver;
        Connection *dbConn;
        Statement *st;
        ResultSet *res;

        driver = mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
        dbConn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "connection");
        dbConn->setSchema("mfc_app_database");

        st = dbConn->createStatement();
        res = st->executeQuery("SELECT password FROM users WHERE id=1");
        string z;
        while (res->next())
        {
            //k = res->getString("username");
            //cs.Format(_T("%s"), k);
            //CString cs(k.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
            //combo.AddString(cs);
            //usernameData.SetWindowTextW(cs);

            z = res->getString("password");
            CString pass(z.c_str()/*, CP_UTF8*/);
            nameData.SetWindowTextW(pass);
        }


        delete res;
        delete st;
        delete dbConn;
        delete driver;
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        ofstream file("sadaasad.txt");
        file << e.what();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Database collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`.
Actually I don't know what I should do... Brain stopped...

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you know you're [slicing the caught exception](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec42c461ba35b35b).

Comment: @chris thanks for your quick response. But I couldn't understand what you mean. Could you explain please?

Comment: Catch the exception as `catch (exception const & e)` .

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried it. But there is no any exception. Program works without stopping working.

Comment: @coni, It was just one problem with the code. Your method of catching exceptions won't respect the overriding done by any derived exception classes.

Comment: @chris, I tried writing variables values to `.txt` file (`std::ofstream` for writing `std::string` and `CFile` for writing `CString` variable value). When I wrote `k` to the file, everything is OK. It wrote the expected value (`nüşabə`). But when writing the `CString pass` value characters change to `nÃ¼ÅŸabÉ™`. 

Actually I couldn't understand that why this happens? I you can please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't this help ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673194/conversion-of-utf-8-char-to-cstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile MFC for UNICODE, [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx) will be defined as a string of `wchar_t` using [UTF16 encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Constructing the `CString` directly from a `char*` like you do, works only if all chars are in the ASCII subset of UNICODE:

- As soon as a unicode char is not ASCII, it will be encoded in UTF8 as several bytes, but the CString constructor then interprets this as two distinct chars.
- This is the case for `nüşabə` with `ü`, `ş`, and `ə`, which each need 2 bytes in UTF8, and cause your CString to be 3 chars longer than expected.

So when you have an UTF8 encoded string in a `char*`, you need to convert it like explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673194/conversion-of-utf-8-char-to-cstring), using `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

**Edit: Code example**

Instead of

```
        CString pass(z.c_str());
```

You could write something like:

```
        wchar_t *p = new wchar_t[z.size()+1];  // UTF16 has same length or less thant UTF8 equivalent
        MultiByteToWideChar(
             CP_UTF8,         // CodePage,
             0,               // flags,
             z.c_str(),       // pointer to UTF8 string
             -1,              // -1 for null terminated string, size otherwise 
             p,               // destination buffer for converted wchar_t string 
             z.size()+1);        // size of buffer
        CString pass(p);
        delete p;
```

Note that [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx) and its reverse `WideCharToMultiByte()` belong to the Windows API and not to MFC.

Note that the standard C++ strings have standard conversion functions that are portable:

```
 wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conversion;
 wstring s = conversion.from_bytes(z.c_str());
 string mbs = conversion.to_bytes(L"\u00c6\u0186");
```

Comment: thanks for answer. It looks very helpful but actually I don't know how to write this code :(

Comment: @coni I've edited with some code to show how to do it.

Comment: oh my dear, thanks very very very very very very much. It solved my problem. Oh my God! thanks again and again !